# Plus sign (+) behaving weirdly in tag

Tags: bug, tags, tag-synonyms

On [Movies & TV Stackexchange](https://movies.stackexchange.com/), we got a new question about 1996's film [Romeo + Juliet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romeo_%2B_Juliet). We are using the tag [romeo-juliet-1996](/questions/tagged/romeo-juliet-1996) for it but I tried to make it more accurate by making it [romeo+juliet](/questions/tagged/romeo%2bjuliet) by synonym method. When I suggested that new tag synonym, it appeared as two different tags [romeo](/questions/tagged/romeo) [juliet](/questions/tagged/juliet) in individual tag synonym section but looked perfectly fine on synonym page (-- /tags/synonyms).

So I approved it and swap/merge it but its working quite weirdly, whenever I click on this tag from question itself, it take me to the page https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/romeo%2bjuliet and url redirection making it into two tags and breaking the link to the older question belongs to same tag. Similarly if I try to edit any question with that tag, it break it into two tags.

So it seems like + is not a supported sign for tag but then why it's even allowed to be entered during synonymization?